# specialize class during dependency injection

Tags: angular, typescript

I have general service class and specialized service classes and common component which should use either of specialzied service, depending on module.

I have `UpdateFormComponent` in `SharedModule` - common for all other modules in application. During instantiating I should pass descendant of `AbstractSaveService` - `Module1SaveService` and `Module2SaveService`. Those services are declared in other modules `Module1` and `Module2`.

So file structure would be

```
\shared\shared.module.ts
        update.form.component.ts
        abstract.service.ts
\module1\save1.service.ts (extends AbstractSaveService)
         users.component.ts (use UpdateFormComponent and Module1SaveService)
\module2\save2.service.ts (extends AbstractSaveService)
         cameras.component.ts (use UpdateFormComponent and Module2SaveService)
```

```
@Component({
    selector: 'update-form-component'
})
class UpdateFormComponent {
    constructor (private s: AbstractSaveService) {}
}
```

```
@Component({
    selector: 'users-component',
    template: '<update-form-component></update-form-component>' // inject Module1SaveService
})
export class UsersComponent {}
```

```
@Component({
    selector: 'cameras-component',
    template: '<update-form-component></update-form-component>' // inject Module2SaveService
})
export class CamerasComponent {}
```

When I'm showing page from `Module1` (`UsersComponent`) and user press button I want to show `UpdateFormComponent` with injected `Module1SaveService`. When I'm showing page from `Module2` (`CamerasComponent`) and user press button I want to show `UpdateFormComponent` with injected `Module2SaveService`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is their a way of programatically knowning which class you want to create? Depending on a global variable, another service value....
Are the 2 instances created inside the same host component? Or in two different hosts?

Comment: @Melou I've edited my question with answers for you.

Comment: Thanks. Does the answer of @Gunter Zochbauer is ok for you? That's why I was asking if the 2 instances are created inside the same host component.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `Special1Service` to providers of the parent of one `MyComponent` and `Special2Service` to providers of the parent of the other `MyComponent`. This means that this only works if both components have a different parent.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent1',
  providers: [{provide: GeneralService, useExisting: Special1Service}],
  template: `<my-component></my-component>`
})
export class Parent1Component {
  constructor(private generalService:GeneralService) {}
}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent2',
  providers: [{provide: GeneralService, useExisting: Special2Service}],
  template: `<my-component></my-component>`
})
export class Parent1Component {
  constructor(private generalService:GeneralService) {}
}
```

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [Special1Service, Special2Service]
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: I think my answer should contain enough information about what is possible using DI. I think you should just inject both services and decide inside the component which one to use (or a similar approach). DI doesn't provide what you want.